# Javascript not working in IE

Tags: javascript

I am having a problem with the auto search javascript in IE. It works correctly in Firefox. To see what I am talking about please visit:

and then start typing the word cart in the search bar. You will see it lines up underneath in Firefox but is not in IE. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function findPos(obj) {
    var curleft = curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
            curtop += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
    }
    return curleft.toString() + ' ' + curtop.toString();
}

(function() {
    var nxt_host = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://" : "http://");
    nxt_host += "vector.nextopiasoftware.com/";
    document.write(unescape("%3C") + "script src='" + nxt_host + "nxt-ac-js-1.3-min.js' type='text/javascript'" + unescape("%3E%3C/script%3E"));
    document.write(unescape("%3C") + "link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='" + nxt_host + "ac-1.3.css'" + unescape("%3E"));
})();
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
    var jnxtac = jQuery.noConflict(true);
    jnxtac("#myInput").css('z-index', '20000');
    jnxtac("#myInput").autocomplete({
        cid: '80c356394c27c27aacf41c465e455f7d'
    });
})();

if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE") != -1) {
    var offsets = findPos(document.getElementById('search')).split(' ');
    var acStyleEl = document.createElement('style');
    var acStyleCss = '.ui-autocomplete {position:absolute !important;left: ' + (parseInt(offsets[0]) + 200) + 'px !important; top: ' + (parseInt(offsets[1]) + 24) + 'px !important;}';
    var bodyEl = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    acStyleEl.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
    acStyleEl.setAttribute("id", "acCssElement");
    bodyEl.appendChild(acStyleEl);
    acStyleEl.styleSheet.cssText = acStyleCss;
}​
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: _"I am not sure if this code is javascript or jquery"_: Well TBH that code seems like a total mess. Honestly, I wouldn't bother trying to fix this, better start from scratch on whatever you're trying to do there.

Comment: IE which version? also try debugging the code and find where is the actual problem

Comment: This is what I was told to put there. I am not a javascript guy so I have no idea how to rewrite it or debug it. I am referring to the latest IE. It's probably the same across all version of IE I imagine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is a problem of css and javascript , in IE your script is breaking due to which the styling is messed up and combox div is shifted to right.

```
d=c.width("").width()
```

This is the code which is breaking.

Have you debugged your application or changed this thing.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Can you tell me where you see this code? I am also not sure how to debug anything using firebug..

Comment: Thank you! I found that piece of code and removed it. It works great now :) How was you able to determine that is where it was breaking?

Comment: in IE developer tools , it throws the error , it seems like code is trying to set the width of the some container.

Answer (score 0):

As other comments have said this is not great code and could be re-written to work better and be much clearer.
However, that said I think the specific problem you have asked about, it not working in IE is because there is an if statement that reads the browser agent(navigator) string and if it contains 'MSIE' it does not show your menu.

```
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE") != -1) {
```

This line gets the browser agent string and if 'MSIE' is not contained (navigator.appVersion.indexOf() will return the index of the start of the string or '-1' if the string is not found) will then execute the remaining code in your function:

```
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE") != -1) {
  var offsets  = findPos(document.getElementById('search')).split(' ');
  var acStyleEl = document.createElement('style');
  var acStyleCss = '.ui-autocomplete {position:absolute !important;left: ' + (parseInt(offsets[0]) +200) + 'px !important; top: ' + (parseInt(offsets[1]) + 24) + 'px !important;}';
  var bodyEl = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  acStyleEl.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
  acStyleEl.setAttribute("id", "acCssElement");
  bodyEl.appendChild(acStyleEl);
  acStyleEl.styleSheet.cssText = acStyleCss;
}
```

The code is convoluted and while I am not positive what teh code in the if statement does, it does not do it in IE and that sounds like your problem...remove the if statement and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I removed the if statement but that didn't seem to change anything. I also removed the entire if statement block and it still is aligning right in firefox. Does that mean there is another script doing this?